# Set object to a variable in another file

Tags: python, tkinter, get, set, call

I want to call a Entry in my main class from a function in another python file.
I discovered, it works with create a list and append it
but not with just "=" why is that so? and how does it work?

**main.py:**

```
from variable import *

number.append(5)
number2 = 5

printer()
printer2()
```

**variable.py:**

```
number = []
number2 = None

def printer():
    print(number[0])

def printer2():
    print(number2)
```

**result:**

```
5
None
```

Another thing  is
i call the widgets that i not created with a for loop by example:

```
self.frame_pm.winfo_children()[0]
```

when i print this i get:

```
.!frame2.!entry
```

can´t i call it direct? like:

```
.!frame2.!entry.config(bg="yellow")
```

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrating on this question: `but not with just "=" why is that so?`, lets look at your code:

`from variable import *`

This line makes four new variables for `main.py`. Its like this code:

```py
import variable
number = variable.number
number2 = variable.number2

printer = variable.printer
printer2 = variable.printer2
```

Concentrating just on `number2` above, when your `main.py` executes this: `number2 = 5` it will just affect the variable `number2` local to this module and not `variable.number2`.